# UWP SQL Server migration not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, uwp, entity-framework-migrations

I installed the latest version of Windows 10 (fall creators update) and Visual Studio 2017 (15.4).

I created an UWP app targeted to major version and installed by Nuget:

- microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools
- microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver

This is my code:

```
[Table("tbProva")]
public class Prova
{
    public Prova()
    {
        Indirizzi = new List<Indirizzo>();
    }

    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Indirizzo> Indirizzi { get; set; }
}

public class ProvaConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Prova>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Prova> builder)
    {
        builder.HasMany(c => c.Indirizzi)
            .WithOne(c => c.Prova)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.IdProva)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}

[Table("tbIndirizzi")]
public class Indirizzo
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string Strada { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string Civico { get; set; }
    public Prova Prova { get; set; }
    public Guid IdProva { get; set; }
}

public class DcContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Prova> tbProva { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Indirizzo> tbIndirizzi { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=Europa;Database=ProvaDb;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration<Prova>(new ProvaConfig());
    }
}
```

If I run migration, I get this result:

```
PM> Add-Migration poi
```

> System.TypeLoadException: Non è stato possibile caricare il tipo 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo' dall'assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

If I remove the navigation properties from model and I do not override `OnModelCreating`, it works fine.

Thanks

Comment: Please make sure to always translate the error messages. We don't all speak your native tongue :-)

Comment: Ok. System.TypeLoadException: unable to load  'System.Globalization.CultureInfo' type by System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a assembly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a known issue,see [issue #9666](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9666).

> While testing EF Core 2.0 with .NET UWP 6.0 we found that there are new types that present similar problems. E.g.:
>   System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>   System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.MarshalByRefObject' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

One example of above exception was  `DataAnnotations`. And in your code snippet just referenced the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace.

And it seems like this patch bug is approved for the 2.0.x patch. See [issue #9827](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9827).

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the [`System.Globalization`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Globalization/) NuGet packge is installed and up-to-date.

Also, if you are going to use EntityFramework please make sure that you installed the `microsoft.entityframeworkcore` package is installed too.

Comment: I installed nuget package and I getting same error. I installed microsoft.entityframeworkcore, too. In your code, does it work?
Thanks

Comment: You could try deleting the `/bin` folder from your project and then click `rebuild solution`. If this doesn't work, I don't know :-/

Comment: Did you try to use ef migrations vs. sql server in uwp before? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I never worked with uwp, but i worked with EF 5, 6 and core aswell as migration and sql server. Honestly the only thing that comes to my mind would be to remove every NuGet package from your solution, clean it (right click solution "clean"), close Visual Studio and re-install every package ... that's what i had to do the last time i ran into a similar error but i'm not sure that it'll fix your problem :-/

Comment: Done, dowsn't work. I tried to create a new uwp app too without success. I created a virtual machine with SO windows 10 insider preview and visual studio 2017 preview and I get same error. Thank you